# InputStream "lags/stuns" app for a while

Tags: java, android, networking, jsoup, inputstream

I have ProgressBar in my Activity, and it is spinning all the time. I'm trying to connect to avaliable web page -
I use InputStream

`InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();`

to get my desired URL. It's working fine. Except one situation: when it starts loading, and I turn off internet connection while this is loading/processing (which not easy to turn it off right in the time, but also not hard), the Progressbar stops spinning, because app is something like 'freezed'. So you can't even quit it with back button. After few seconds, like 3-4, the ProgressBar is spinning again and app is unfreezed and fully working.
LogCat only prints that app skipped many frames.

Code:

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
      public void run()
      {
            try
            {
                InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
                ...

            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
      }
 }).start();
```

**Edit:** I'm using Jsoup to read received webpage. So I tried

`Jsoup.connect(url).get();`

too, but same problem as above...

LogCat:

> Skipped 614 frames!

**Log2**

```
10-14 17:25:16.365 26460-26460 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
10-14 17:25:16.375 26460-26460 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
10-14 17:25:16.375 26460-26460 D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
10-14 17:25:16.395 26460-26460 D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-14 17:25:27.406 26460-26460 I/Choreographer: Skipped 603 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: You need to set a read timeout and handle the `SocketTimeoutException` that arises when it triggers. There is no other way for code that is just reading from a socket to detect a cable pull.

Comment: In most cases it pass trough this exception (and it's all good, no freeze), but sometimes it just doesn't pass, and nothing is print (except skip frames message). Check another log I added in main post, it's the one where it didn't passed exception block (check seconds time gap - that's the freeze). Btw, how do I set timeout for InputStream? It's possible for Socket only AFAIK. Should I use Sockets instead of InputStream? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'pass through this exception' or indeed any of that, but if you don't catch it separately you can't handle it separately.

Comment: @EJP Exception is called most of time (~in 3/4 cases), and when it's called, there's no problem with freezing UI. But when it's called not, UI is freezed for a while. That was my mean of 'pass through this exception'. Btw, no idea why exception is not called. But it happens only when some bytes are already received and rest is still loading from internet.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion is a bad practice to spawn threads in Java. Especially in Android. There are threadpools that handle this in a better way.

In your case use AsyncTask:

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      try
        {
            InputStream input = new URL(url).openStream();
            ...

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: Your opinion is not an answer, and you haven't addressed the actual question.